# products having overlapping timestamp, how to query in Redshift

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, amazon-redshift, overlap

I have an issue, were want to tag overlapping timestamp group by a product.

how to query product details which are owned by different owner between same timestamp?

Sample data:

| owner | product | beginDate | endDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | one | 2015-08-01 | 2017-09-10 |
| B | one | 2017-09-26 | 2019-09-10 |
| C | one | 2019-09-01 | 2020-01-05 |
| D | two | 2015-08-01 | 2017-06-21 |
| E | two | 2017-08-01 | 2018-09-08 |
| F | two | 2017-12-03 | 2018-11-30 |
| G | two | 2018-12-01 | 2020-09-10 |

Desired output:

| owner | product | beginDate | endDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| B | one | 2017-09-26 | 2019-09-10 |
| C | one | 2019-09-01 | 2020-01-05 |
| E | two | 2017-08-01 | 2018-09-08 |
| F | two | 2017-12-03 | 2018-11-30 |

Answer (score 0):

Join the table to itself, and say that the comparison must have the same product, different owner, and the begindate must be between the begin/end date of the other records:

```
with cte AS (
select t1.owner     AS t1owner,
       t1.product   AS t1product,
       t1.begindate AS t1begindate,
       t1.enddate   AS t1enddate,
       t2.owner     AS t2owner,
       t2.product   AS t2product,
       t2.begindate AS t2begindate,
       t2.enddate   AS t2enddate
from yourschema.yourtable t1

inner join yourschema.yourtable t2
    ON t1.product = t2.product
        AND t1.owner != t2.owner

where t1.begindate between t2.begindate and t2.enddate
)

select
        t1owner AS owner,
        t1product AS product,
        t1begindate AS begindate,
        t1enddate AS enddate
from cte
union all
select
        t2owner AS owner,
        t2product AS product,
        t2begindate AS begindate,
        t2enddate AS enddate
from cte
```

Result:

```
+-----+-------+----------+----------+
|owner|product|begindate |enddate   |
+-----+-------+----------+----------+
|B    |one    |2017-09-26|2019-09-10|
|C    |one    |2019-09-01|2020-01-05|
|E    |two    |2017-08-01|2018-09-08|
|F    |two    |2017-12-03|2018-11-30|
+-----+-------+----------+----------+
```